# How is diagonal block distance measured in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For example, let's say you start at point A. You move 5 blocks north and 12 blocks east and arrive at point B. Is it 13 because of the Pythagorean theory, or is it measured some other way? Does this work with vertical distances too? The reason I'm asking this is because I'm having trouble with my mob trap in the sky and im trying to figure out the distances i can still move while having the spawner work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natural mob spawning distances work in a Euclidean sphere (not cylinder from top to bottom, nor taxicab sphere). So the Pythagoras's theorem should work.

[image: Mob spawning sphere]

Note that this does not apply to **all** distances in Minecraft. Lighting, for example, uses a taxicab sphere, and mob spawner blocks use a cuboid.

Comment: hm it seems like i always have to be between 16 and 24 blocks away from where mobs spawn for mobs to spawn and to walk around? It seems like a really short range

Comment: @Ovi According to the diagram above (and it took me going No thats not right a few times) mobs will spawn between the 24m and 32m range AND move around. Mobs will spawn between the 32 and 128 range as well but their AI will not make them move. If your mob farm requires them to move around on their own then yes, it is a very small range for that to happen within. If however you have a spawn on a platform with a string trigger and get pushed off by a piston... then you may be able to use the whole range. This is speculation on data though, I have not built a mob farm in a long time.

Comment: Could you add a source for this image? Is this something you put together? If its external, I would love to see what other information the source has to offer.

Comment: @EliasBenevedes this image is from the wiki article on [Spawn](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn?cookieSetup=true#Despawning), under the Despawning header.